# Exclude data based on the number of non NA observations for each value of key

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset consisting of monthly observations for returns of US companies. I am trying to exclude from my sample all companies which have less than a certain number of non NA observations.

I managed to do what I want using `foreach`, but my dataset is very large and this takes a long time. Here is a working example which shows how I accomplished what I wanted and hopefully makes my goal clear

```
#load required packages
library(data.table)
library(foreach)

#example data
myseries <- data.table(
 X = sample(letters[1:6],30,replace=TRUE),
 Y = sample(c(NA,1,2,3),30,replace=TRUE))

setkey(myseries,"X") #so X is the company identifier

#here I create another data table with each company identifier and its number 
#of non NA observations
nobsmyseries <- myseries[,list(NOBSnona = length(Y[complete.cases(Y)])),by=X]

# then I select the companies which have less than 3 non NA observations
comps <- nobsmyseries[NOBSnona <3,]

#finally I exclude all companies which are in the list "comps", 
#that is, I exclude companies which have less than 3 non NA observations
#but I do for each of the companies in the list, one by one, 
#and this is what makes it slow.

for (i in 1:dim(comps)[1]){
myseries <- myseries[X != comps$X[i],]
}
```

How can I do this more efficiently? Is there a `data.table` way of getting the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than 1 column you wish to consider for NA values then you can use `complete.cases(.SD)`, however as you want to test a single columnI would suggest something like

```
naCases <- myseries[,list(totalNA  = sum(!is.na(Y))),by=X]
```

you can then join given a threshold total NA values

eg

```
threshold <- 3
myseries[naCases[totalNA > threshold]]
```

you could also select using not join to get those cases you have excluded

```
 myseries[!naCases[totalNA > threshold]]
```

As noted in the comments, something like

```
myseries[,totalNA  := sum(!is.na(Y)),by=X][totalNA > 3]
```

would work, however, in this case you are performing a vector scan on the entire data.table, whereas the previous solution performed the vector scan on a data.table that is only `nrow(unique(myseries[['X']]))`.

Given that this is a single vector scan, it will be efficient regardless (and perhaps binary join + small vector scan may be slower than larger vector scan), However I doubt there will be much difference either way.

Comment: As a `data.table` novice, would something like: `myseries[,i:=sum(is.na(Y)),by=X][i < 3]` work?

Comment: @thelatemail Yes! The only reason I used complete cases, was in case in their real example had more than one column they were interested in. The reason I used a join + vector scan is that my vector scan will be slightly faster (as it is a smaller data.table). The speed difference would be (almost certainly) negligible

Comment: @mnel Actually my data table has many columns but I am only interested in testing one of the columns for NAs (the column which contains the returns). Also, your solution seems to count the number of NAs, but I want to count the number of non NAS (I don't care how many NAs there are or there are not, as long as I have at least "threshold" number of non-NA observations). I adapted the code to my needs and it seems to work, but I am still working on it.

Comment: @Vivi I've adjusted the answer.

Comment: That's the problem with giving simple examples. I am running into a problem with the real data. The join line is giving me an error: TM' is a character column being joined to i.'PERMNO' which is" type 'integer'. Character columns must join to factor or character columns.". Do you know what this is? Is it simple to solve? (TM and PERMNO are both keys in my data.table)

Comment: @Vivi -- I can't answer your data-related questions without an example of your data. It is probably due to the order of your keys (you want `X` in your example here to be the first key column in your data.table

Comment: @mnel OK, I removed the second key and it worked. My old code was taking more than 30 minutes to run, now it takes a few seconds. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

How about aggregating the number of NAs in Y over X, and then subsetting?

```
# Aggregate number of NAs
num_nas <- as.data.table(aggregate(formula=Y~X, data=myseries, FUN=function(x) sum(!is.na(x))))

# Subset
myseries[!X %in% num_nas$X[Y>=3],]
```

Comment: I will try now with my dataset and see if I understand your way, cheers

Comment: Great. Just noticed I had it backwards (was selecting X with less than 3 non-NA Y, `num_nas$X[Y<3]`) and fixed it in the code. The problem is I gave a bad name to the aggregate (num_nas, when actually I was counting the number of complete cases!)

Comment: Why would you use `aggregate` instead of data.table? This is not a more efficient method, and definitely NOT a data.table solution.

Comment: Ha, it is certainly more efficient than the `for(...)` loop, just like @Vivi asked. And you already provided a `data.table` solution, so I provided an alternative, non-data-table one. So, why the pip?

Comment: It may avoid the for loop, but a data.table solution is more efficient memory wise -- Your solution (in your word description) is reasonable (and far better than the for loop, basically what my answer does too). If you are not going to use data.table, you might as well, go the whole hog, and not bother coercing num_nas to data.table

Comment: I will probably choose the data.table way in the end for a number of reasons, but any solution which is faster than mine is really helpful (especially since I am still learning R!).